# Dirac bra-ket operator notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation, linear-algebra

a simple question about Dirac notations:

Let $|a\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$ and $|b\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} b_{1} \\ \vdots \\ b_{n} \end{pmatrix}$.

Then what is the matrix representation of $|a\rangle\langle b|$?

Comment: Hint: $\langle i|a\rangle\langle b|j\rangle=a_ib_j^\ast$.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly you shouldn't use an equals sign here. I will use the rightarrow to stand for 'is represented by'. Then
$|a\rangle \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$,  $\;|b\rangle \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} b_{1} \\ \vdots \\ b_{n} \end{pmatrix}$,
$\;\;\;\;\;|a\rangle \langle b| \rightarrow 
\begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n} \end{pmatrix} 
\left( b_1^* \cdots b_n^* \right)
= 
\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
a_1 b_1^* & a_1 b_2^* & \cdots & a_1 b_n^* \\
a_2 b_1^* & a_2 b_2^* & \cdots & a_2 b_n^* \\
\vdots & \vdots  &  & \vdots \\
a_n b_1^* & a_n b_2^* & \cdots & a_n b_n^* 
\end{array} \right)
$

The final combination is called an outer product; it satisfies the rules of matrix multiplication. Here we had a $(n \times 1)$ multiplying a $(1 \times n)$ object, giving an $(n \times n)$ result.

Answer (score 3):

Use your definitions of a dyadic,
$$|a\rangle\langle b|=  
  \begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\  \vdots \\ a_{n} \end{pmatrix}\otimes (  b_{1}^* ,     \ldots  ,  b_{n}^*  )=   \begin{pmatrix} a_{1}b_{1}^* &   \ldots &  a_{1}b_{n}^*  \\ \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots\\   a_{n}b_{1}^* &   \ldots &  a_{n}b_{n}^*  \end{pmatrix} . $$